# How to subtract two numbers and get a negative number in NASM?

Tags: windows, gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I have this code that is supposed to subtract two numbers, a float (10.25) and an integer (15):

```
extern _printf
global _main
section .bss
  num1: resb 4
  num2: resb 4
section .data
  format_number: db "%f", 10, 0
section .text
_main:

  mov dword [num1], 15
  mov dword [num2], __float32__(10.25)

  sub esp, 8
  fild dword [num2]
  fsub dword [num1]
  fstp qword [esp]
  push format_number
  call _printf
  add esp, 12

ret
```

The output I get is:

> 1092878336.000000

The output I expect is:

> -4.750000

How to get the result that I expect?

Comment: You are using `fild` to load `num2` which you already stored in memory as a float. You may have been looking for something like `sub esp, 8`
  `fld dword [num2]`
  `fisub dword [num1]`
  `fstp qword [esp]` . FISUB takes the integer value at [num1] converts it to extended precision float and then subtracts that value from the top of  the FPU stack which already contains 10.25

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thank you very much, I did not know `fisub`. I will read the tutorial you told me, in my previous question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

```
extern _printf
global _main
section .bss
  num1: resb 4
  num2: resb 4
section .data
  format_number: db "%f", 10, 0
section .text
_main:

  mov dword [num1], 15
  mov dword [num2], __float32__(10.25)

  sub esp, 8
  fld dword [num2]
  fisub dword [num1]
  fstp qword [esp]
  push format_number
  call _printf
  add esp, 12

ret
```

The output I get is:

> -4.750000

Thanks @MichaelPetch, your answer was the solution. ^_^